# Building a Graph Editor - How to create a data driven graph

Tags: javascript, json, graph, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm developing a graph-editor that uses drag and drop to build hierarchical graphs (containing nodes and links), each node in the graph should be linked to a table in our database (SQL Server), I did a lot of research about libraries based on javascript or/and JSON specifications to draw nodes and links, there are a lot of great examples to follow. But I have no idea about the way I can link a graph to a database (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...). I thought about this architecture :

[image: Technical Architecture]

I have looked at the [D3](http://d3js.org/) library , It creates Data driven charts but I think It only uses flat files, and not relational databases. 
First can you please tell me if my architecture is well thought out? And secondly can give me some ideas about the way I can link my graphs to the DBMS.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting question, but it might be overly broad to fit this site. Perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that a node is deserialized as the following POCO:

```
public class Node
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public List<int> outBoundConnection {get;set;}
    public List<int> inBoundConnection {get; set;}
}
```

The id field is from the database. This is what you will use to keep track of the object. Assuming each row/node/.. has a unique id, you need to keep this around through out the life cycle of the object (Query -> POCO -> JSON -> D3). This id will link your D3 dataset to your SQL server rows.

I hope this helps as a general outline.

> 1. Set up a web project, which will expose web services that D3 will use.
> 2. Create a web service to query the nodes. Return data as JSON.
>
>    > [D3 has API for web serivces](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)
>
> > You might want to look in to [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), as it makes it     super easy to convert from DataTable/Reader to POCO. Or a DTO/OOM Framework in your favorite language.
> >
> > In this web service: Create a connection to database, query needed tables, execute the query, turn the returned data in to a class object (AutoMapper), return what ever structure you constructed as JSON.

Now, since the id is kept throughout the life cycle, you can make requests to your web service with the id as the parameter.

So, for example, if you wanted to delete a note. You would make an HTTP DELETE request ([jQuery comes in handy here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to a web service endpoint that accepts an id as a parameter.

Or if you want to remove a connection node, create a web service that takes two ids, or the id of the connection (if you have the schema set up that way).

You want to hook on to something unique about the graph data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very nice ideas.. Don't you think however that using a web service will slow down the process ? since It will be called at each node creation or update ?

Comment: You can return a list of nodes to D3. So if you had 100 nodes that you wanted to display when the page loads, the web service would return a list of 100 nodes. You would have to change the D3 code to work with lists of nodes instead of just nodes.

Comment: Yes good advice, I can try to return a list of nodes instead of passing one by one...